# Close SQL connection Nodejs

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server, database-connection

I tried to close the connection for the below query by using connection.close(). but it is not working, so how to close connection inside **route file**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var connection  = require('../database.js');
var db  = require('../database.js');


 
/* GET home page. */
 router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  connection.query("Select users..... ",function(err,supervisorrows)     {

             if(err){
          req.flash('error', err); 
          res.render('View',{page_title:"Users - Node.js",supervisor:''});   
         }else{
            
             res.render('View',{page_title:"Users - Node.js",supervisor:supervisorrows.recordset});

         }                     
        });




 
module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

According to mysql npm docs There are two ways to end a connection :

- `connection.end()` method
- `connection.destroy()` method

The first one will make sure all previously enqueued queries are still before sending a COM_QUIT packet to the MySQL server.

The second one terminates a connection immediately and guarantees that no more events or callbacks will be triggered for the connection.